# how to use value from main query in sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Im trying to run a sub-query that based on one of the main query values but i always get 0 as VALUE.
This is my query :

```
SELECT ID,(
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM  `post_meta` 
    WHERE  `post_id` 
    IN (
        SELECT  `ID` 
        FROM  `wp_posts` 
        WHERE  `post_title` = posts.ID
    )
) AS counter
FROM wp_posts;
```

if i run only the sub-query with id number instead of posts.ID it returns a good value.

Comment: I think you still have something mixed up.  I am assuming you meant `wp_posts.ID` due to your comment on jjs9534 answer.  So, how can you have `wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_id` and also `wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_title`?  That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it does not seem right but it is, the last programmer who built this database didnt do a good job with it so the post_title sometimes used for titles and sometimes to store id, if i change the WHERE `post_title` = posts.ID to `post_title` = 5161 it works fine, so this part is ok,

Comment: I still don't understand the logic.  If your `post_meta.post_id` is always populated then you couldn't you just leave off the `wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_title` completely.  Part of the problem might be your comparing two different data types.

Answer (score 5):

I do believe a simple join in the sub query will get you the correct COUNT:

```
SELECT posts.ID,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM post_meta
  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_ID
  WHERE wp_posts.post_title = posts.ID  
) AS counter
FROM posts;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed by giving the table a custom name so i can use it when im going in two layers this is how the code look after the change :

```
SELECT ID,(
SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM  `post_meta` 
    WHERE  `post_id` 
    IN (
        SELECT  `ID` 
        FROM  `wp_posts` 
        WHERE  `post_title` = my_posts.ID
    )
) AS counter
FROM wp_posts as my_posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

Linger you beat me to it but I was going to suggest leaving out the subquery altogether if I can guess what the structure looks like.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN post_meta ON wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.ID = post_title
GROUP BY ID
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN post_meta ON wp_posts.ID = post_meta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.ID = post_title
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, I had a mistake when writing this query there is only wp_posts table (no posts table) 
I have tried to write the query with inner join as you suggested but  had no success, how can i write this query in my case? (i have edited the question)

Comment: I edited my answer based on your edit. It looks like you are just asking for the number of meta posts for a particular post id.

Comment: that's correct but both of the queries do not work, the first one dont fetch any row and the second one get always 0 as a value like it was before

Comment: *@user2326568*, see, my comment above on your question, you have something mixed up still.

Comment: @Linger that is what I was thinking too, it looks like he is comparing post title to post id, but hey...